# What bonus experience can you get?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have just completed my first multiplayer game in the new expansion where you receive XP for doing different things.

I got 25% bonus XP for playing with friends, are there other things I can do to get bonus XP like this?

[image: Screenshot of the Experience tab of the Starcraft 2 Victory! screen showing (highlighted) message "Play with a Friend Bonus: +25% XP"]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feature isn't fully implemented just yet, so there aren't much ways to get bonus experience at the moment.

Blizzard has stated the following in an interview with PC Gamer (prior to game release):

> We’re already working on concepts like “bonus XP for your first win
> of the day” and “extra XP when you play in a party with a Battletag or
> Real-ID friend”
>
> We’re considering “bonus XP weekends” and other sorts of activities,
> which will be tested in the beta.

Aside from playing with a friend and first win of the day, it doesn't seem that there is other ways to get bonus experience as of right now.

It seems that the first win of the day bonus can be awarded for every race.

Comment: If you look just over the box it says "First Zerg win of the day bonus"

Comment: Hmm I only play one race, so didn't put much thought in that 'First win of the day' bonus, perhaps you can get it 3 times a day (4 if they count Random as a race).

Comment: I played as random in that game so I guess only 3 times

Comment: In Beta there were three independent "first win with race" bonuses. I also believe I saw a screenshot with "Match Time Bonus: +25%" somewhere, but cannot find it, and I'm not even sure if this is a bonus for *shortness* (but it likely is).