# What bonuses does your Starcraft 2 level provide?

Tags: starcraft-2

I haven't bought SC2: HotS yet but from the question "[What bonus experience can you get?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108504/what-bonus-experience-can-you-get)"

I can see that you now gain some experience after a battle? If so,

- What effect does it have if your profile is "Level 5" or something?
- Do you get transferred to a higher league?
- Do you have in game bonuses for single player?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having a higher level unlocks decals, portraits, unit skins and Animation(/dance command) for units in that race that can be used in multiplayer.

At this time max level is 30.

1. *nothing*
2. Decal
3. Portrait
4. Decal
5. Portrait
6. *nothing*
7. Decal
8. Portrait
9. Decal
10. **Animation**: Overlord, Mule, Stalker
11. Portrait
12. *nothing*
13. Decal
14. Portrait
15. **Animation**: Roach, Viking, Oracle
16. Decal
17. Portrait
18. *nothing*
19. Decal
20. **Skin**: Overlord, Supply Depot, Pylon
21. Portrait
22. Decal
23. Portrait
24. *nothing*
25. **Animation**: Infestor, Ghost, Colossus
26. Decal
27. Portrait
28. Decal
29. Portrait
30. **Skin**: Zergling, Marine, Zealot

---

At level 1, 6, 12, 18 and 24 it dose not look like there is any reward, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: dances? like unit animation or more of videos? Thanks by the way for the quick reply

Comment: you can make some units dance by selecting them and typing /dance in the chat

Answer (score 1):

Spending resources and destroying enemy units and buildings in multiplayer earns you experience at a rate of 1 unit of spent/destroyed minerals/gas = 1 exp point. There is a soft cap of 50.000 exp per battle, any exp above that gets cut to 33%.

"Multiplayer" here means any non-campaign match, including custom games vs AI (not sure if non-starcrafty custom game modes are also excluded).

Experience levels are per-race, and award decals, portraits and other stuff. Sum of all race levels is your profile level, which is just an e-peen measure :-)

Answer (score 0):

It unlocks new skin for certain units, new portraits and new decals.

http://shokzguide.com/starcraft-2-guides/general-guides/heart-of-the-swarm-levels-and-rewards/