# Strategies to earn StarCraft 2 experience bonuses?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know that earning experience points from StarCraft 2 matches [awards a variety of things](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108646/559). What I am unsure of is beyond the **first match of the day** and **speed bonuses** what other bonuses exist.

Winning quickly and playing once a day are easily implemented strategies, but what other experience point bonuses exist and what are the strategies for earning them?

Comment: Play a lot rather than looking for experience "hacks" otherwise you will soon find yourself in masters having a hard time winning games thus making the game less fun

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg very sound advice, but I might change my play style during a match if I know hey if I do X at this point I'm going to get an XP bonus.