# What game modes can I earn XP in?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Heart of the Swarm you can gain XP as each race by building units and killing enemy units. XP gain is obviously disabled in the campaign, and obviously enabled in ranked multiplayer matches.

Is XP gain enabled in any of the following?

- unranked multiplayer matches (via matchmaking)
- vs AI matches (via matchmaking)
- melee matches (via custom game)
- arcade matches

For the modes in which it is enabled, do I earn full XP in all of them or are there any that offer reduced XP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "In the Heart of the Swarm leveling system, players earn experience while playing Blizzard matchmaking  modes and custom games on Blizzard maps."

Quote taken from [Heart of the Swarm's experience preview](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/7681240).

Here's what I can add from my own online endeavors:

Yesterday I've played a ranked match, got experience for it. I also went ahead and completed the 3 levels from the new online 'tutorial' they created, got experience for that too.

But it's pretty clear from what Blizzard said, that you'll gain experience for pretty much any game you play online, be it versus AI or players, as long as you're playing on Blizzard made maps.

Answer (score 4):

XP can be gained in multiplayer games only which involve a standard game (aka not a custom game, or what use to be called a 'used map settings' game in Starcraft 1).  You can play against [computers or other users Ranked or Unranked](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/7747193) and gain XP.

Heres is the [original announcement](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/7681240) during the beta for XP.

There is also many ways to get [Bonus EXP](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108504/what-bonus-experience-can-you-get) which would make leveling even faster!

Answer (score 2):

From the [2.01 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/7747193) you gain XP for:

> playing Ranked and Unranked matchmaking games or when playing Custom Games on Blizzard melee maps.

Full XP will be gained in any game that awards it.

Answer (score 0):

You gain XP from all games; tutorial, vs AI, unranked, ranked.